# How to "clean up", itertools combinations output?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

I'm trying to merge some text files by combining every element (line) with the others.

I have something like:

```
wordlist.txt -> alfa
                bravo
                charlie

numlist.txt -> 123
               234
               345

spec.txt -> ?
            !
            %
            $
```

I'm using itertools to get the combinations.

This is my script:

```
row1 = []
f_w1 = open(dictionary_word, 'r')
for line in f_w1.readlines():
    line = line.split()
    row1.append(line)
  ... 

inputdata = row1, row2, row3

combinations = list(itertools.product(*inputdata))

combinations_path = input('Enter a directory to save the combinations file: ')

with open(combinations_path + "userscombinations.txt", 'w') as f:
    for s in combinations:
        f.write(str(s)+ '\n')

with open(combinations_path + "userscombinations.txt", 'r') as f:
    combinations = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

print(combinations)
```

I would need to obtain a single file such as:

```
combinations.txt -> alfa123?
                    alfa123!
                    alfa123%
                    .......
                    charlie345$
```

But with itertools I get something like:

```
combinations.txt -> (['a'], ['1'], ['?'])
(['a'], ['1'], ['!'])
(['a'], ['1'], ['"'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
words = ["alfa", "bravo", "charlie"]
nums = ["123", "456", "789"]
specs = ["?", "!", "%", "$"]
```

you can use `"".join` to reduce each combination to a single string.

```
from itertools import product

combinations = ["".join(x) for x in product(words, nums, specs)]
```

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_Files.py", line 37, in <module>
    combinations = ["".join(x) for x in product(row1, row2, row3)]
  File "PassPhraseGen_3_Files.py", line 37, in <listcomp>
    combinations = ["".join(x) for x in product(row1, row2, row3)]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: I'd look carefully at what values `row1`, `row2`, and `row3` actually have. They may differ from `words` et al. as shown in this answer.

Comment: Specifically, your description makes it sound like each line of an input file contains exactly one item, in which case `line = line.split()` turns `"alfa"` unnecessarily into `["alfa"]`.

Comment: Thanks, actually the variable "row1" is an array -> row1 = [], if I print its values I get -> [['alfa'], ['bravo'], ['charlie']]

Comment: I would either get rid of the call to `split` (it seems unnecessary), or use `row1.extend(line)` (if it is necessary).

Comment: As I needed to create a .txt file (such as a dictionary), I had to remove the \n at the end of every element in some way. I solved by using line.split('\n'). Thank you all guys.

Comment: That's what `strip` (and its more precise siblings `lstrip` and `rstrip`) are for. `line = line.rstrip('\n')` will remove trailing newlines and *only* trailing newlines from `line`.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is in the loop that's reading the file, specifically in `split()` (use `strip()` instead), it should be as follows for all three files:

```
for line in f_w1.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    # use strip instead of split to remove trailing and leading whitespaces
    row1.append(line)
```

Then, to turn combinations into strings use `str.join`:

```
combinations = [''.join(comb) for comb in itertools.product(*inputdata)]
```

Output test:

```
['alfa123?', 'alfa123!', 'alfa123%', 'alfa123$', 'alfa234?', 'alfa234!', 'alfa234%', 'alfa234$', 'alfa345?', 'alfa345!', 'alfa345%', 'alfa345$', 'bravo123?', 'bravo123!', 'bravo123%', 'bravo123$', 'bravo234?', 'bravo234!', 'bravo234%','bravo234$', 'bravo345?', 'bravo345!', 'bravo345%', 'bravo345$', 'charlie123?', 'charlie123!', 'charlie123%', 'charlie123$', 'charlie234?', 'charlie234!', 'charlie234%', 'charlie234$', 'charlie345?', 'charlie345!', 'charlie345%', 'charlie345$']
```